# Fitting an MLE estimate of hierarchical models when marginalization is intractable

Tags: bayesian, estimation, maximum-likelihood, multilevel-analysis, intractable-likelihood

How we can get an MLE estimate of a hierarchical model, when we cannot marginalize due to intractability of the integral?

As I understand it, if we have the closed form marginal distribution e.g. Poisson-Gamma mixture, then it would be as straight forward as doing MLE (via gradient descent or something) to find the parameters for the Gamma distribution.

But if we do not have a nice mixture, the marginalization does not have a closed form.

In the case of intractability, how might we approach MLE that is computationally efficient?

Comment: Could you give a specific example?  (Something more than "if we do not have a nice mixture")

Comment: @JimB, a "nice mixture" would be the Gamma-Poisson, which has a closed form for the marginal likelihood distribution (which is what is used for inferring probabilities for example). An example of a non-tractable marginal likelihood would be the Poisson - Lognormal model. They both are overdispersed Poisson distributions in effect.

Further research into the literature shows that we can use numerical methods such as EM, and Laplace approximation to estimate the parameters of such models. But I am still unclear about how probabilistic inference on them works. .e.g P(X = x | est'd params)

Comment: Again, would you give a specific example in the text?  A numerical optimization approach  needs specifics.

Comment: I don't know if I have an example from a text, as I am experimenting/learning about formulating hierarchical models with these conditions. A possible model that I am thinking about is modeling events over time as a Hawkes Process, where we use the Gamma distribution as a mixing distribution for the baseline intensity.  Given this model, I'd like to infer P(X(t) = x) for example. The probability function still needs to integrate out the mixing distribution, but it is not available in closed form. Does this give you a better idea of what I am asking?

Comment: I'll try one more time:  Please provide a specific example in the text of your question.

Comment: Adding information and details inside the comments does not help to make the question better and more useful to others. @JimB request is about including the Poisson-LogNormal model inside the main text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use "data cloning", a numerical method which tricks a Bayesian MCMC algorithm into providing maximum likelihood parameter estimates and their standard errors:  Lele et al. 2007.  Data cloning:  easy maximum likelihood estimation for complex ecological models using Bayesian Markov chain Monte Carlo methods.  Ecology Letters 10:551-563.  Available here:  [https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~brian/reprints/Lele_et_al_Ecology_Letters_2007.pdf](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Ebrian/reprints/Lele_et_al_Ecology_Letters_2007.pdf)